# Casting or converting from Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>>

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have an object defined as

```
public class MessageQueue
 {
     public string MsgTitle { get; set; }
     public string ClientID { get; set; }
     public string UserID { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method that is deined as

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> DataFromDatabase()
 {
     //  This function returns IEnumerable<dynamic>. 
     // The data comes from Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultipleAsync() 
 }
```

How can I cast the data returned from this method, that's IEnumerable to an object of type MessageQueue? I have tried several options, including the following, but still it fails at runtime:

```
IEnumerable<MessageQueue> result = (IEnumerable<MessageQueue>)(IEnumerable<dynamic>)srv.DataFromDatabase().Result;
List<MessageQueue> messageQueue = (List<MessageQueue>)result.Select(o => (MessageQueueToSendRet)o);
```

Comment: Have your tried using LINQs .Cast<MessageQueue>()?

Comment: IEnumerable<dynamic> result = srv.DataFromDatabase().Result;
var messageQueue = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)result).Cast<MessageQueue>().ToList(); But it gives me a runtime error Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' to type 'MessageQueue'.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = srv.DataFromDatabase().Result;
List<MessageQueue> messageQueue = result.Select(o => 
    new MessageQueue() 
      {
         MsgTitle = o.MsgTitle.ToString(), 
         ClientId = o.ClientId.ToString(), 
         UserID = o.UserID.ToString()
      } ).ToList();
```

So you might as well do the mapping inside DataFromDatabase where Dapper will do the work for you.

Comment: This generates a runtime error Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' does not contain a definition for 'MsgTitle'

Comment: If `o` is a `List<object>` you're `DataFromDatabase()` is probably messed up.  You'll need to post its implementation.

Comment: Dapper.SqlMapper.QueryMultipleAsync() was always returning an object. I chnaged it to SqlMapper.QueryAsync<T>(). 
Your code contribution was greate, but I simplied it to  
var messageQueue = result.Select(o => (MessageQueue)o).ToList();

but also I could use

var messageQueue = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)result).Cast<MessageQueue>().ToList();